# MongoDB HeartbeatException: > "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, configuration, mongodb-atlas

> System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a
> server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
> LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
> } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
> : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
> [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/mongodb.net:27017" }",
> EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server. --->
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> receiving a message from the server. --->
> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the
> stream. at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.d__4.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__54.MoveNext() ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__57.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.d__16.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.d__6.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__32.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__34.MoveNext()", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-06-12T09:49:42.7901777Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-06-12T09:49:42.7901777Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream. at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__54.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__57.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.d__16.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.d__6.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__4.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext() ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__32.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__34.MoveNext()",
> LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-06-12T09:49:42.7602069Z",
> LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-06-12T09:49:42.7602069Z" }, { ServerId: "{
> ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
> "Unspecified/mongodb.net:27017" }",
> EndPoint:
> "Unspecified/mongodb.net:27017",
> ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: ,
> TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
> "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> opening a connection to the server. --->
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
> receiving a message from the server. --->
> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the
> stream. at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.d__4.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__54.MoveNext() ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__57.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.d__16.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.d__6.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__51.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__32.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__34.MoveNext()", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2021-06-12T09:49:42.7401803Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2021-06-12T09:49:42.7401803Z" }] }. at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1
> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at GetUserDetails();

```
  public List<User> GetUserDetails(Guid applicationID, Guid UserID)
        {
            var con = new MongoClient(DBConnection.MongoDBConnectionString);
            var db = "UserDB"
            var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("User");
            var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("userid", UserID.ToString())
                      & (Builders<User>.Filter.Gt("expiryDate", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()));
            var users= collection.Find(filter).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.userstatus).ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).ToList();
            return users;
        }
```

**My Connection string format**

```
<add name="MongoDefaultConnection" connectionString="mongodb+srv://appname:corfjg#5r@appname.nbf92.mongodb.net/UserDB?retryWrites=true" />
```

Comment: Any help here? I am facing exact same problem